# SQL search between 2 dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've got a database that needs to display records between 2 dates.

At the moment I've got a form with 2 text boxes on - one for `datefrom` and one for `dateto`.

My plan was to format and store the values from these text boxes as global variables

```
DateFrom = Format(Me.DateFrom, "yyyy/mm/dd")
DateTo = Format(Me.DateTo, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

that I cam then pass into a passthrough query with this criteria for  field called dateCollected

```
HAVING (((Collections.DateCollected) str_to_date(datefrom, ‘%y/%m/%d’) and str_to_date(dateto, ‘%y/%m/%d’)) AND ((dbo.udfRawHazPropsList([ConsignmentNoteNumber],[ewc_code])) Is Not Null))
```

However, no matter what I try I can't get this to work. Any ideas as to a solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with SQL Server.  Either explain why you are using MySQL syntax or change the tag to the database you are really using.

Comment: Use `where` not `having`. Test for an actual range.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get it by two ways:**

**1.** If your sp variable of `date` type-

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-07-23',
        @EndDate DATE = '2020-07-27'

SELECT * from TableName 
WHERE CreatedON between @StartDate and @EndDate   --First Way

SELECT * from TableName 
WHERE CreatedON >= @StartDate and CreatedON <@EndDate --Second Way

SELECT * from TableName 
WHERE CreatedON between CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,6) 
and CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,6) --Third Way
```

**2.** If your sp have `Varchar` Variable type-

```
DECLARE @StartDate1 VARCHAR(50) = '2020-07-23',
        @EndDate1 VARCHAR(50) = '2020-07-27'

SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE CreatedON between CAST(@StartDate1 AS DATE) 
and CAST(@EndDate1 AS DATE)  --First Way

SELECT * from TableName 
WHERE CreatedON >= CAST(@StartDate1 AS DATE) 
and CreatedON < CAST(@EndDate1 AS DATE) --Second Way

SELECT * from TableName 
WHERE CreatedON between CONVERT(varchar,Cast(@StartDate1 AS date),6) 
and CONVERT(varchar,Cast(@EndDate1 AS date),6) --Third Way
```

In Third way in both, you can change the value to get the different format.
`CONVERT(varchar,Cast(@EndDate1 AS date),6)`
Change Third Value to get different format if you need.

Comment: One would hope OP is not using a `varchar` to hold a date.

Comment: Yes Right  @Dale . Actually, It is not expected !! It is for those who did wrong implementation in table column. I just want to make it for all !! Expected, It should be date/datetime.